# Node.js hasOwnProperty does not work even when the property exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, hasownproperty

In my Node.js Express application, when the user is logged in via passport the user user object is saved in the request.

It looks something like this:

```
{
    "uuid": "caa5cb58-ef92-4de5-a419-ef1478b05dad",
    "first_name": "Sam",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "sam@email.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$fXYBeoK6s.A8xo2Yfgx4feTLRXpdvaCykZxr7hErKaZDAVeplk.WG",
    "profile_uuid": "db172902-f3c9-456d-8814-53d07d4ea954",
    "isActive": true,
    "deactivate": false,
    "verified": true,
    "ProviderUuid": "7149f8f1-0208-41db-a78e-887e7811a169"
}
```

But not every user has the ProviderUuid key present. So before using its value I am trying to check if the ProviderUuid key is present in the user object

```
var user = req.user;
console.log('---- provider: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
console.log('--- prop: ' + user.hasOwnProperty('ProviderUuid')); //returns false
console.log('---- other method prop check: ' + Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(user, "ProviderUuid")); //returns false
if('ProviderUuid' in user){
    //this returns true
}
```

So doing `user.hasOwnProperty('ProviderUuid'`) and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(user, "ProviderUuid"))` returns false, however `'ProviderUuid' in user` returns true.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please check http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-uses-of-in-vs-hasownproperty.html may help you

Comment: can you please check demo: https://repl.it/@idanimob/AquaGracefulMicrostation
its return true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `in` works, the property must an *inherited* property, on one of `user`'s prototype objects, rather than being on `user` itself. Here's a live example of such behavior:

```js
const userProto = { foo: 'bar' };

// Create an empty object named `user` whose internal prototype is `userProto`:
const user = Object.create(userProto);

// False, user itself is an empty object, nothing's been assigned to it:
console.log(
  user.hasOwnProperty('foo')
);

// True, `foo` does exist on the *internal prototype* of the `user` object:
console.log(
  'foo' in user
);

// True, `foo` is a property directly on `userProto`:
console.log(
  userProto.hasOwnProperty('foo')
);
```

So, if you want to check for the existence of an inherited property named `ProviderUuid`, use the `in` operator like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I tested code and all checks returned true.

```js
var user = {
    "uuid": "caa5cb58-ef92-4de5-a419-ef1478b05dad",
    "first_name": "Sam",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "sam@email.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$fXYBeoK6s.A8xo2Yfgx4feTLRXpdvaCykZxr7hErKaZDAVeplk.WG",
    "profile_uuid": "db172902-f3c9-456d-8814-53d07d4ea954",
    "isActive": true,
    "deactivate": false,
    "verified": true,
    "ProviderUuid": "7149f8f1-0208-41db-a78e-887e7811a169"
};
console.log('---- provider: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
console.log('--- prop: ' + user.hasOwnProperty('ProviderUuid')); //returns false
console.log('---- other method prop check: ' + Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(user, "ProviderUuid")); //returns false
if('ProviderUuid' in user){
    //this returns true
}
```

Try JSON.parse(), Maybe `req.user` saved as string